# Арап как название чернокожего

Tags: этимология

Откуда в русском языке взялось слово "арап" для обозначения чернокожих? Если от слова "араб", то, во-первых, почему Б изменилось на П, а во-вторых, арабы ни разу не чернокожие и к неграм отношения не имеют.

Comment: 1. [Арабы][1] и вообще арабская культура распространилась на территорию всей южной оконечности Средиземного моря.
2. Арапы необязательно были именно совсем уж чернокожими. Все люди разных цветов. На мой взгляд, уже жители южных широт России существенно темнее, чем типичные жители СПб и Москвы. Что уж говорить о людях со средиземноморским загаром...

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За спорами все (кроме разве barnard'a) как-то забыли ответить на вопрос.

Споры "из турецкого или из арабского" бессодержательны. В русский иначе как через турецкий попасть не могло. В европейских другое значение (то самое, которое сейчас в русском), а прямые контакты с арабами были минимальны.

Изменение конечного согласного (иногда - и не конечного) на близкий смущать не должно. В русском это частое явление: сват<свад(свадьба), шкаф<шкап, матрас<матрац, колодец<колодезь и проч. Хотя причины здесь могут быть разные, но специальных исследований проводить смысла нет, ничего кроме изменений фонетики за такими вариациями не стоит. 
Касательно значения. Выскажу предположение, что, прежде чем стать современным, значение менялось несколько раз. Собственно, это не противоречит Черных.

Изначально (до и во времена Петра) оно, видимо, означало только чернокожего африканца, потом распространилось на всякого жителя Африки. При этом огромное количество употребительных синонимов делало значение нестабильным, это в общем-то достаточно общий закон, язык полной синонимии не терпит. Далее, с появлением необходимости как-то различать представителей арабского и негроидного населения Африки значение мигрировало в сторону "белого африканца (неевропейца)". А дальше уже по Черных. Замечу только, что современное значение уже никак не связано с Африкой.

Answer (score 3):

Да, сейчас это два разных слова, но в старину означали одно и то же,произносили всегда арап, имея в виду жителей "Арапии", с географией были проблемы.До сих пор в словарях можно встретить:Араб - устар. арап, мурин, мавр, сарацин, агарянин. Арап(устар.) - алжирец, аравиец, бедуин, египтянин, иракец, йеменец, кувейтец, ливиец, мавританец, марокканец, мориск, оманец,палестинец, сириец, тунисец.Как видите, здесь арабы перемешаны с африканцами.
 В старину у славян арабами (или арапами) называли негров.Арап – турецкое слово. Здесь арапами называют  чернокожих африканцев. Раньше чернокожие в Турцию попадали в качестве рабов. В русский язык слово пришло из турецкого или близкородственного ему татарского языка. 
И сейчас в восточном углу Средиземноморья чернокожих называют арабами, а в западном конце, в Испании, арабов зовут “черными”. Правда, не испанским словом negro – черный, откуда пошло во многие языки название чернокожих, а moro – мавр, тоже черный, темный, только по-гречески. Имя árabe в литературном испанском языке тоже есть, но в простом разговоре соседей через Гибралтар продолжают по старинке звать маврами.После террористической акции арабов в 2003 году возмущенные испанцы говорили в телекамеру: “moros... мавры сделали это”.Они же не негров имели в виду.

Арап — это ещё и должность при дворе, занимаемая иногда и белыми, а не только арапами, т.е. черными, простыми людьми низкого происхождения. Есть арап — вездеход-минитрактор.(Видимо, сильный и выносливый, как чернокожий раб ). Есть понятие БЕЛЫЙ АРАП- белокожий представитель Аравии.
Арапом иногда называли ребенка, родившегося в смешанном браке с чёрным или цыганом.

Answer (score 2):

Есть в русском языке два простых, я бы даже сказала, простейших слова. Звучат они (по крайней мере, в именительном падеже единственного числа) одинаково, а вот пишутся по-разному. Это слова «арап» и «араб».

Чтобы было понятно, что слова разные, произнесем-ка их во множественном числе: «арапы» и «арабы». Так сразу становится ясно, что различаются они последним согласным звуком - /П/ и /Б/. Да и вообще - разные. Чтобы понять, когда писать и говорить «арабы», а когда «арапы», надо разобраться, что эти слова означают.

Начнем с «араба». Из словаря Ожегова мы узнаём, что арабы - это народы семитической (или семитской) языковой группы, населяющие Ближний Восток и Северную Африку. А вот с происхождением слова всё сложнее. В словаре Фасмера (этимологическом) нас отсылают к французскому языку: там есть слово orobe - так, может быть, это и есть источник? Вряд ли, потому что откуда-то это слово должно было сначала прийти во французский.

Другой словарь, Историко-этимологический (автор - П.Я. Черных), считает, что слово «араб». появилось, собственно, в самом арабском языке (что логично). 
Это - «араб».
Но вспомним Пушкина и его «Арапа Петра Великого». Арап - прадед нашего великого поэта - был не «арабом», а именно «арапом», то есть негром. Ну и правда, в словаре Ожегова читаем, что «арап» - это чернокожий, темнокожий человек, негр. Причем, заметьте, мы чернокожих людей давно арапами не называем. Словари это отражают: слово «арап» признано устаревшим. Откуда оно пришло? Скорее всего, из тюркских языков - предполагают этимологи. 
Но и это еще не всё про«арапа». Так называли мошенников, мелких жуликов. Именно мелких, заметьте. Если пойти дальше и заглянуть в словарь воровского жаргона, то мы выясним еще одну прелюбопытную деталь: и там был «арап». У уголовников «арап» - это игрок-аферист, лицо, торгующее валютой. «Гнать арапа» означало попросту лгать, а «арапа заправлять» - не платить проигранную сумму.

Comment: А ссылку на первоисточник? Плагиат!!!

Comment: Конечно, плагиат!Такие исследовательские работы требуют времени, доступа к архивным документам и т. п. Над этим работают профессионали и не один день. Когда мы объясняем этимологию какого-то слова, ссылаясь на исследования Фесмера, Даля и т. д.,  мы же не воспринимаем данные исследовательских (чужих!!!) работ как плагиат, а благодарим кликом "за" того, кто побеспокоился и нашел правильный ответ. Я думаю, что этот материал Вам понравился и Вы захотели его прочитать, а на счет плагиата Вы просто пошутили.См. http://www.moiraion.ru/news/stat_all/x_20080124140425.php

Comment: Да насчет плагиата я, конечно, пошутил. Мне просто не понравилось, что текст один в один как тот, который по ссылке, но ссылки самой не было. Спасибо, что дополнили.

Comment: Текст, может быть, с литературными достоинствами, но по информативности не дотягивает до того, чего ждешь от такого объема.

Comment: Если Вы нашли другой материал, который дотягивает по информативности - пожалуйста, предоставьте такую возможность другим прочитать более познавательный материал. Источники разные.Желаю удачи!!!

Answer (score 2):

Согласно  ИЭС  П.Я.  Черных, "арап" - первоначальное  заимствание  из  тюркских - обозначало  чернокожих,  но  к  середине  XIX  было  вытеснено  из  литературного  языка  словом "негр".  Вероятно  с  этого  времени  в  литературе  закрепляется  западнно-европейское  "араб"  в  значении  близком  к  современному.